# fatal: division by zero attempted

Tags: linux, awk, cron, top

The below command is successful if run in a shell script.

```
top -n 1 |  awk 'FNR ==4 {print $5/$3*100}'
67.7902
```

It does not work, however, if run from a cron job.  Hence I changed the command but now `awk` is giving an error.

```
top -b -n 1 |  awk 'FNR ==4 {print $5/$3*100}'
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of: `top -b -n 1 |  awk 'FNR == 4 {print}'`

Comment: Are you interested in the division of your free memory by total memory ? If so, please try: `top -b -n 1 |  awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "} FNR == 4 {print $6/$4*100}'`.  In principle the `BEGIN` block is not necessary (default) but we don't know what else your actual use case may include, so better safe than sorry. _[tested on Arch linux with `awk` v.5.1.0 with `top` from procps-ng 3.3.16]_

Comment: top -n 1 (without -b) outputs an ncurses version of the screen, crammed with terminal control characters. The interesting question is: why did you get so lucky with the line and field numbering in the first version? My $3 is `:^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[1m`, but the whole thing depends acutely on the TERM=... value in the environment.